# How to separate the data by name of rows in r?

Tags: r, text-files

Sorry if this is a dulpicate but I couldn't find the answer. I have a men.txt file containing data for young and old men like:

```
"BalanceMeasure" "Age_group"
26.272722832203 "elderly"
23.4572384621414 "elderly"
28.0295727143824 "elderly"
26.6261784908838 "elderly"
14.5754428676468 "young"
18.5711350938964 "young"
6.03642481885425 "young"
15.2875928698119 "young"
16.8511145817837 "young"
17.4018884973852 "young"
```

This only shows a fraction of the actual txt file I have to use I just wanted to show what I meant. I need to isolate the data according to the "young" and "elderly" and find out the mean.
I tried this:

```
> data1 <- subset(balancedata_0, Age_group == "young")
> data2 <- subset(balancedata_0, Age_group == "elderly")
```

But that only gave me a list of the words "young" and "elderly". So how would I get all the numbers associated with "young" men in one data set and the numbers associated with "elderly" men in another data set.

Comment: to get the means per group: `unique(ave(balancedata_0$BalanceMeasure, balancedata_0$Age_group))`

Comment: `aggregate(data=Balance,BalanceMeasure~Age_group, FUN=mean)`. `Balance` is the dataset here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with `split()`:

```
age_list <- lapply(split(balancedata_0,balancedata_0$Age_group), `[[`, 1)
#$elderly
#[1] 26.27272 23.45724 28.02957 26.62618

#$young
#[1] 14.575443 18.571135  6.036425 15.287593 16.851115 17.401888
```

and extract the mean values with

```
lapply(age_list,mean)
#$elderly
#[1] 26.09643
#
#$young
#[1] 14.78727
```

**data**

```
balancedata_0 <- structure(list(BalanceMeasure = c(26.272722832203, 23.4572384621414, 
 28.0295727143824, 26.6261784908838, 14.5754428676468, 18.5711350938964, 
 6.03642481885425, 15.2875928698119, 16.8511145817837, 17.4018884973852), 
 Age_group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L), 
 .Label = c("elderly", "young"), class = "factor")), 
 .Names = c("BalanceMeasure", "Age_group"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: The data I provided is only a fraction of what is actually in the txt file. Should've made that clear to begin with, sorry.

Comment: @RyanFasching Do you have any problem or error message using this code? I don't think it should represent a difficulty in large data sets, and I believe that it also performs quite well.

Comment: No but there's way too many data points to manually enter them into the *df1 <- structure(list(BalanceMeasure = c()*

Comment: It is not necessary to enter anything manually. If your data is stored in a data.frame with a name, say `balancedata_0`, you can just replace `df1` with `balancedata_0`. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @RyanFasching to follow up on this, RHertel shared your data in the way we wish you had originally shared it: he posted the output of `dput(balancedata_0)`. This is nicer than the way posted in your question because it is copy/pasteable into R and it preserves classes and structure.